# How nextLine() method works

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Consider the code :

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestClass
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Scanner input= new Scanner ("34\n567");

      while(input.hasNext())
      {
          System.out.println(input.nextLine());
      }

      input.close();
  }
}
```

the output I get:

```
34
567
```

When I try to read the string by `nextLine()`, it should not read it like this as it has to terminate only at line separator and `\n` is not line separator in Java.

So how does this happen?

Comment: Please share some piece of code. Check the length of `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Comment: What do you mean '\n' is not a line separator[in Java] ? What is it then ? [assuming you are on linux]

Comment: @kiruwka ,assume you are not on linux then it is not line separator.

Comment: Read the doc for [nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()). It's basically smart enough to figure out where line separators are, regardless of if they are ``\n`` or ``\r\n``.

Comment: @Braj , i have edited my question to make i more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
    String s = "a\r\nb";
    for (String str : s.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"))) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    System.out.println("Length:"+s.split(System.getProperty("line.separator")).length);
```

`\r\n` represents new line.

output

```
 a
 b
 Length:2
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question, which is why ``nextLine()`` works even though the user is, depending on platform, returning ``\n`` or ``\r\n``

Comment: Question is not clear to me. I have requested OP to share some piece of code. I think it might help OP.

Comment: here is line separator used in `Scanner` class `\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]`

Comment: It will work for all these cases `34\r567` , `34\n567` and `34\r\n567`

Comment: I think now you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

nextLine() is base in the regulare expression "\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]". This accepts any line break of the supported plattforms of java and is not limited to plattform this instance of the jvm is actually running on. In fact most methods in java for detecting a line break work this way. Thus it's not really correct that there's a definition how the line break should look like.